# Azure Media Services v3 CreateEvent Hangs

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-media-services

I am using the example code from [The Azure GitHub page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-tutorials/tree/master/NETCore/Live). I've been messing with it for a few hours, sometimes the LiveEvent.Create works pretty instantly, sometimes it just hangs. Right now its going on 50 minutes. Can someone help with what i'm doing wrong? Is there a way to figure out why this is hanging? If we are using this in a live production, not having reliable start times is a real problem. This is the line it fails on:

```
liveEvent = client.LiveEvents.Create(config.ResourceGroup, config.AccountName, liveEventName, liveEvent, autoStart:true);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Even the comments in the code says `The following operation can sometimes take awhile. Be patient.`

Comment: I do see that, but its now going on 90 minutes.

Comment: Yeah I can see how that is a bit excessive.

Comment: Have you tried finding the source code to see what that call does internally?

Comment: 90 minutes is very excessive. Can you send details to amshelp@microsoft.com with your subscription ID, region, account name and the time period this happened at please

Comment: @ChrisKooken - is your Media Service account in the East US 2 region? If so, could you please create another account in East US or West US regions, and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was found to be specific to the region (East US 2), where the necessary resources had not been configured correctly. A hotfix has been deployed to fix it, and you should be able to create and use LiveEvents in this region.

Comment: Yes. This was the problem. I engaged MS support and they confirmed the bug. All is fixed now.